# Transaction Succeeding in Firestore but lands up in onFailure

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am running a transaction in firestore like this:

```
final DocumentReference deleteRef = db.collection("ABC").document("XYZ");

db.runTransaction(new Transaction.Function<Void>() {
    @Override
    public Void apply(Transaction transaction) throws FirebaseFirestoreException {
        DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = transaction.get(deleteRef);
        if(documentSnapshot.exists())
        {
            transaction.delete(deleteRef);
            Log.d("MyActivity", "inside documentSnapshot.exists()");
            Log.d("MyActivity",deleteRef.getPath());

        }
        return null;
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // implement logic
        Log.d("MyActivity","onSuccess");
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        Log.d("MyActivity","onFailure");
        Log.e("MyActivity", "transaction failure", e);
    }
});
```

Logs of Client A:

> 2019-10-21 20:28:45.134 15866-16240/someapp D/MyActivity: inside
>   documentSnapshot.exists()
>
> 2019-10-21 20:28:45.134 15866-16240/someapp  D/MyActivity: ABC/XYZ
>
> 2019-10-21 20:28:45.488 15866-15866/someapp  D/MyActivity: onSuccess

Logs of Client B:

> 2019-10-21 20:28:46.041 30293-31123/someapp D/MyActivity: inside
>   documentSnapshot.exists()
>
> 2019-10-21 20:28:46.041 30293-31123/someapp D/MyActivity: ABC/XYZ
>
> 2019-10-21 20:28:47.900 30293-30293/someapp  D/MyActivity:
>   onFailure
>
> 2019-10-21 20:58:04.137 6537-6537/someapp  E/MyActivity:
>   transaction failure
>       com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Transaction failed all retries.
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.lambda$transaction$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1:283)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine$$Lambda$2.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1:205)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>        Caused by: com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException: Every
>   document read in a transaction must also be written.
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.commit(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1:182)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.lambda$transaction$1(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1:270)
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine$$Lambda$1.then(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:272) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$DelayedStartFactory.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@19.0.1:205) 
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Now, 2 clients A and B are near simultaneously running this transaction. As one would expect, if Client A lands up in onSuccess, Client B lands up in onFailure.

But, unexpectedly, both the clients are deleting the document.

In other words, even if the transaction lands in onFailure for Client B, it deletes the document, which should not be case.

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Please log the exception in onFailure and show it here.  `Log.e("MyActivity", "transaction failure", e);`

Comment: Yes, I have done the same

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using 19.0.1

Comment: That's not the latest version - be sure to update it.  If you still have clear steps to reproduction with the most recent SDK, please file a bug with Firebase support so that they can reproduce and confirm the issue. https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 2):

Only the first client is actually deleting the document.  The second client would see a non-existent document.

You might also want to know that deletes in Cloud Firestore don't generate an error.  Also, gets on documents also do not generate errors for documents that don't exist.

So actually, with the code you're showing, the second client would see `documentSnapshot.exists()` return false, and nothing would happen in the transaction, because `exists()` also doesn't generate any errors.

If you're seeing a client end up in a failure, try logging the exception to see what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In both cases, according to my log, it goes inside the `if(documentSanpshot.exists())` though.

Comment: Are you positive it's the same document both times?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the log statements and the log output.